# How to make YouTube video private to allow viewing only for specific people (using new Studio Beta, 2019)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-channel, youtube-studio

I'm trying to make one video private so that I can share it only with a few people. But every tutorial that I can find shows how to do it the old way, I guess, and it doesn't match what I see on the screen.

When I go to my YouTube page, the video manager looks different. It says, "Studio Beta" and when I set my video `private` and want to specify people to share it with, all it gives me is this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it now?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way for this in the beta yet. You'll need to return to the Classic version (link is in the bottom left corner of the Beta), and then do it [the old way](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177?hl=en):

> 1. Go to your Video Manager in Creator Studio Classic.
> 2. Find the video you want to share, then select Edit.
> 3. Beneath the "Privacy Settings" drop-down menu, select Share.
> 4. Enter the email addresses of people you'd like to share your video with, then select OK.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I hope they don't remove that feature.